# how to use a responsive html templete in a Spring application?

Tags: html, spring, jsp, responsive-design

I'm trying to use a shiny responsive-design html 5 template on top of the Spring application I'm working.

Question is: how to connect the HTML files with the JSP and the Spring controllers?

Comment: Responsive has nothing to do with spring integration. It is handled by css and js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use just about any templating engine with Spring. You typically just need to set up a Resolver for it. See [here](https://spring.io/blog/2012/10/30/spring-mvc-from-jsp-and-tiles-to-thymeleaf/) for an example.