# How to properly configure my SpringMVC 4 application to use Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, maven, thymeleaf

My application is, currently, on a stage where I can start working on the view layer. Though JSPs are exceptional at speed, I'd like to try using a HTML5 template from [wrapbootstrap.com](http://wrapbootstrap.com/). In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734424/how-to-use-a-responsive-html-templete-in-a-spring-application/35735996#35735996) I asked how to do it, and the idea was to use a templating engine like Thymeleaf.

So I added to my pom.xml the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And added the following bean to my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "b.c.m.h")
public class HConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        return viewResolver;
    }
    (...)
}
```

There a mapping on my controller defined as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
    return "welcome";
}
```

This mapping says that URLs ending with `"/"` or `"/home"` should be handled by the page on `WEB-INF/html/welcome.html`.

I'm getting a null pointer when I try to access `"/"`.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/h] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:202)
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:149)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try to use `ServletContextTemplateResolver` instead of `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver`

Comment: Nope, same `NullPointerException`...

Comment: If you want to use the ClassLoaderTemplateResolver you should make sure that your templates are stored in the classpath. The prefix should point to a valid classpath location.NB. In web applications /WEB-INF is not part of classpath resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change like following:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");

    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(engine);

    return viewResolver;
}
```

Comment: OK, got something different now: `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "welcome", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

Comment: That was a little error in prev answer. I returned `templateResolver`, but you should return `viewResolver`. I updated it.

Comment: OK, I was missing a `/` at the end of `templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html");`.