# org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="login", line 36 - column 3

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, saxparseexception

Before changing the original source, I'm attempting to access the default login page for a [wrapbootstrap.com](http://wrapbootstrap.com) template. Use of templating engine was solved in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979484/how-to-properly-configure-my-springmvc-4-application-to-use-thymeleaf/35979621?noredirect=1#comment59613793_35979621).

My ViewResolver bean is defined by:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "b.c.m.h")
public class HConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        return viewResolver;
    }
    (...)
}
```

But, when I try to access the `login.html` page defined by:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage() {
    return "login";
}
```

And the `login.html` page being:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Beyond Admin - Responsive Admin Dashboard Template build with Twitter    Bootstrap 3
Version: 1.3
Purchase: http://wrapbootstrap.com
-->

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--Head-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Login Page</title>

    <meta name="description" content="login page" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">

    <!--Basic Styles-->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link id="bootstrap-rtl-link" href="" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--Fonts-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,600,700,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

    <!--Beyond styles-->
    <link id="beyond-link" href="assets/css/beyond.min.css"    rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/demo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link id="skin-link" href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!--Skin Script: Place this script in head to load scripts for skins    and rtl support-->
    <script src="assets/js/skins.min.js"></script>
</head>
<!--Head Ends-->
<!--Body-->
<body>
    <div class="login-container animated fadeInDown">
        <div class="loginbox bg-white">
            <div class="loginbox-title">SIGN IN</div>
            <div class="loginbox-social">
                <div class="social-title ">Connect with Your Social Accounts</div>
                <div class="social-buttons">
                    <a href="" class="button-facebook">
                        <i class="social-icon fa fa-facebook"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="" class="button-twitter">
                        <i class="social-icon fa fa-twitter"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="" class="button-google">
                        <i class="social-icon fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="loginbox-or">
                <div class="or-line"></div>
                <div class="or">OR</div>
            </div>
            <div class="loginbox-textbox">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
            <div class="loginbox-textbox">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
            <div class="loginbox-forgot">
                <a href="">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
            <div class="loginbox-submit">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Login">
            </div>
            <div class="loginbox-signup">
                <a href="register.html">Sign Up With Email</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="logobox">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Basic Scripts-->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

    <!--Beyond Scripts-->
    <script src="assets/js/beyond.js"></script>


</body>
<!--Body Ends-->
</html>
```

I get this error on console:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/hrm] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="login", line 36 - column 3] with root cause
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 36; columnNumber: 3; The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1749)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:332)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.doParse(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:209)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplateUsingPool(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:134)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplate(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:116)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:278)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:149)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:149)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:68)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Which claims `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 36; columnNumber: 3; The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>"`. But at line 36 there's only `</head>`.

I noticed the `<link>` element on the `<!--Fonts-->` section does not ends with a `</link>` or `/>` but it does not seems to matter whether I correct it or not.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,600,700,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

The above is missing the `/` just before the closing `>`

The error message was quite explicit:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 36; columnNumber: 3; 
    The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".
```

Comment: I had noticed that, but it doesn't matter if I insert the `/` before `>` or not, but I have inserted it anyway. Eclipse does shows a warning on that line that reads `Tag (link) should be an empty-element tag`, though.

Comment: You have confused Eclipse by using the .html extension. It wants to validate it as HTML, not as XML which is what Thymeleaf needs.  This is an unresolvable conflict unless you use a different file extension.  You can just ignore Eclipse's warnings.

Comment: And whether you should use `/>` or `</link>`: while it doesn't really matter to an XML parser (both are well formed), only `/>` is correct as far as HTML is concerned. `link` is a void element that does not have an end tag. See the W3C validator.

Answer (score 2):

This happens since the HTML file is has some wrong HTML5 syntax. You can get rid of this using [LEGACYHTML5 template mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624768/thymeleaf-strict-html-parsing-issue).